# WPF - how to get XAML from exe

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reflection

My task is to get all running window aplication list, then by selecting one of them I'll have to serialize the GUI to XAML. Is it possible? I have no clue how to start.

Comment: You need to serialize GUI of some running application into Xaml?
And what do you mean by `serialize`?

Comment: Yes, I want to save all controls (like button, label etc.) to XAML file.

Comment: I'd start with an empty window which can load any XAML by compiling it runtime to a usercontrol and then adding it to the empty window (dock.fill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the application you want to target is WPF, you can get a headstart looking at the code of [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).